# Attribute error during binary search tree?

Tags: python, search, binary-search-tree, preorder

I'm trying to write software to print a BST containing strings in preorder, and this is the code I have so far. for some reason it will print the first two strings and then it will crach and give me a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'" error

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.count = 1

def insert(root, value):
    if not root:
        return Node(value)
    elif root.value == value:
        root.count += 1
    elif value < root.value:
        root.left = insert(root.left, value)
    else:
        root.right = insert(root.right, value)
    return root

def create(seq):
    root = None
    for word in seq:
        root = insert(root, word)
    return root

def preOrder(root):
    print(root.value)
    print("root.value printed")
    if root.left != 0:
        preOrder(root.left)
    if root.right != 0:
        preOrder(root.right)


src = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'barfoo', 'overflow', 'python']
tree = create(src)
print(preOrder(tree))
```

This is the output it will give me:

```
foo
root.value printed
bar
root.value printed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 37, in <module>
print(preOrder(tree))
File "", line 29, in preOrder 
preOrder(root.left)
File "", line 29, in preOrder 
preOrder(root.left)
File "", line 26, in preOrder 
print(root.value)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I can't pin down why this is happening? I know this error means it's pointing at something that doesn't exists, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is to change your `preOrder` method to stop when `root` is `None`:

```
def preOrder(root):
    if root is None:
        return
    print(root.value)
    print("root.value printed")
    if root.left != 0:
        preOrder(root.left)
    if root.right != 0:
        preOrder(root.right)
```

Also, you don't need `print(preOrder(tree))`, you can just do `preOrder(tree)`, since all it does is print the tree. Otherwise you will get an extra `None` printed, which is the default return of a method that does not return anything.

Your indentation in your question is wrong, but I assume that is accidental.